# SortedVector from Vector

Tags: java, sorting, inheritance, vector, overloading

(Learning task - got stuck) I need to make a class (`SortedVector`) that extends `Vector` always sorting the elements. Can't figure out how to overload the `addElement` method. I must use `Collections.sort`.

```
public class SortedVector extends Vector {
    public void addElement(Object o){
        super.add(o);
        Collections.sort(); //what do I do here?
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: Which is the object that you want to be sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to sort the current collection - so just pass `this` to `Collections.sort`:

```
public class SortedVector extends Vector {
    public void addElement(Object o){
        super.add(o);
        Collections.sort(this); // Note the usage of this
    }
}
```